# Python, convert all entries of list from string to float

Tags: python, list, types

I am brand new to Python and looking up examples for what I want to do. I am not sure what is wrong with this loop, what I would like to do is read a csv file line by line and for each line:

- Split by comma
- Remove the first entry (which is a name) and store it as `name`
- Convert all other entries to floats
- Store `name` and the float entries in my `Community` class

This is what I am trying at the moment:

```
class Community:
    num = 0
    def __init__(self, inName, inVertices):
        self.name = inName
        self.vertices = inVertices
        Community.num += 1

allCommunities = []
f = open("communityAreas.csv")
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    entries = line.split(',')
    name = entries.pop(0)
    for j, vertex in entries: entries[j] = float(vertex)

    print name+", "+entries[0]+", "+str(type(entries[0]))

    allCommunities.append(Community(name, entries))
f.close()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
>>>>> PYTHON ERROR!!! Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alexChicago.py", line 86, in <module>
    for j, vertex in entries: entries[j] = float(vertex)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

It may be worth pointing out that this is running in omegalib, a library for a visual cluster that runs in C and interprets Python.

Comment: It looks like there's more than two columns in your CSV file.

Comment: There are a variable number of columns. There is always one name but generally many vertices. **Edit**: I am just testing the first one, not all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot the `enumerate()` function on line 86; should be

```
for j, vertex in enumerate(entries): entries[j] = float(vertex)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was silly of me. Getting used to Python syntax

Answer (score 1):

If there's always a name and then a variable number of float values, it sounds like you need to split twice:  the first time with a maxsplit of 1, and the other as many times as possible.  Example:

```
name, float_values = line.split(',',1)
float_values = [float(x) for x in float_values.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I may not be absolutely certain about what you want to achieve here, but converting all the element in `entries` to `float`, should not this be sufficient?: Line 86:

```
entries=map(float, entries)
```